# Create a state dropdown with an abbreviation option and a full option

Tags: php, form

I have this simple function here because I am too lazy to write out a state dropdown every time I need one. I already have an array with all the states set up, abbreviations as keys and names as values. It works just fine, but I like to write concise, clean, legible code, and I am still very unseasoned, so I find I miss a lot of stupidly simple s*** (the price I pay for teaching myself and not practicing often enough).

I see the four lines of redundant code inside the two primary conditionals, and I would move them outside the `if` statement, except that I have that last echo statement, which is really the whole purpose for the condition in the first place, and I don't think retesting the `$style` variable is all that kosher.

```
function create_state($style, $form = NULL) {
  global $state;
  echo '<select name="state">'."\n";
  echo '<option value="">--</option>'."\n";
  if ($style === 'abbr') {
    ksort($state);      
    foreach ($state as $abbr => $name) {
      echo "<option value=\"$abbr\"";
      if($form === $abbr)
        echo 'selected="selected"';
      echo ">$abbr</option>\n";
    }
  } else {
    asort($state);      
    foreach ($state as $abbr => $name) {
      echo "<option value=\"$abbr\"";
      if($form === $abbr)
        echo 'selected="selected"';
      echo ">$name</option>\n";
    }
  }
  echo '</select>'."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume here (having done this myself before when I first started out with PHP), that you are storing the state data in a MySQL database, which you are pulling and storing in the `global $state` var.

Do not do that. You're slowing down the entire program by making a call out to the database for what is pretty much static data (the last state to join the union joined 55 years ago).

Now, I would just have the dropdowns stored in functions which just return a string. One function for long name, one for abbreviated.

However, using this as an exercise for you in DRY, I went ahead and created a class, `StateDropDown`, which contains an associative array of states/properties and their abbreviation. On initiation, the class generates the output form. If the `$style` contains 'abbr', then we use the abbreviated version after performing a `ksort()`. Otherwise, since the data in the array is static and already sorted as we prefer, we don't perform an `asort` and just go straight to storing the select form in a property `$output`.

```
class StateDropDown{
    protected $states = array(
        "Alabama" => "AL",
        "Alaska" => "AK",
        "Arizona" => "AZ",
        "Arkansas" => "AR",
        "California" => "CA",
        "Colorado" => "CO",
        "Connecticut" => "CT",
        "Delaware" => "DE",
        "Florida" => "FL",
        "Georgia" => "GA",
        "Hawaii" => "HI",
        "Idaho" => "ID",
        "Illinois" => "IL",
        "Indiana" => "IN",
        "Iowa" => "IA",
        "Kansas" => "KS",
        "Kentucky" => "KY",
        "Louisiana" => "LA",
        "Maine" => "ME",
        "Maryland" => "MD",
        "Massachusetts" => "MA",
        "Michigan" => "MI",
        "Minnesota" => "MN",
        "Mississippi" => "MS",
        "Missouri" => "MO",
        "Montana" => "MT",
        "Nebraska" => "NE",
        "Nevada" => "NV",
        "New Hampshire" => "NH",
        "New Jersey" => "NJ",
        "New Mexico" => "NM",
        "New York" => "NY",
        "North Carolina" => "NC",
        "North Dakota" => "ND",
        "Ohio" => "OH",
        "Oklahoma" => "OK",
        "Oregon" => "OR",
        "Pennsylvania" => "PA",
        "Rhode Island" => "RI",
        "South Carolina" => "SC",
        "South Dakota" => "SD",
        "Tennessee" => "TN",
        "Texas" => "TX",
        "Utah" => "UT",
        "Vermont" => "VT",
        "Virginia" => "VA",
        "Washington" => "WA",
        "West Virginia" => "WV",
        "Wisconsin" => "WI",
        "Wyoming" => "WY",
        "American Samoa" => "AS",
        "District of Columbia" => "DC",
        "Federated States of Micronesia" => "FM",
        "Guam" => "GU",
        "Marshall Islands" => "MH",
        "Northern Mariana Islands" => "MP",
        "Palau" => "PW",
        "Puerto Rico" => "PR",
        "Virgin Islands" => "VI",
        "Armed Forces Africa" => "AE",
        "Armed Forces Americas" => "AA",
        "Armed Forces Canada" => "AE",
        "Armed Forces Europe" => "AE",
        "Armed Forces Middle East" => "AE",
        "Armed Forces Pacific" => "AP"
    );
    public $output = "";

    public function __construct($style = false, $form = null){
        if($style === true){
            ksort($this->states);
        }

        $this->output = "<select name='state'>";
        $this->output .= "<option value=''>--</option>";

        foreach($this->states as $name => $abbr){
            $this->output .= "<option value='" . $abbr . "'";
            if($form === $abbr){
                $this->output .= "selected='selected'";
            }

            if($style === true){
                $this->output .= ">" . $abbr . "</option>";
            } else {
                $this->output .= ">" . $name . "</option>";
            }
        }
        $this->output .= "</select>";
    }
}
```

To use, simply instantiate and echo output.

Here, we do a regular state name, with no selected state:

```
$dropdown = new StateDropDown();
echo $dropdown->output;
```

Here, we do a regular state name, with a selected state, NY:

```
$dropdown = new StateDropDown(null, "NY");
echo $dropdown->output;
```

Here, we do an abbreviated state name, with no selected state:

```
$dropdown = new StateDropDown(true);
echo $dropdown->output;
```

Here, we do an abbreviated state name, with a selected state, FL:

```
$dropdown = new StateDropDown(true, 'FL');
echo $dropdown->output;
```

While we may have the overhead of instantiating a new object, etc - we save on a possible database call. Additionally, we no longer do multiple checks, but rather do one check for abbreviation preference and assume the non-abbreviated by default, as well as keeping it non-abbreviated sort by default.

**EDIT**

Since OP indicated that I was incorrect in my assumption that they were storing this data in a database, I've modified my above Class into a function which does the same thing:

```
function statesDropdown($style = false, $form = null){
    $states = array(
        "Alabama" => "AL",
        "Alaska" => "AK",
        "Arizona" => "AZ",
        "Arkansas" => "AR",
        "California" => "CA",
        "Colorado" => "CO",
        "Connecticut" => "CT",
        "Delaware" => "DE",
        "Florida" => "FL",
        "Georgia" => "GA",
        "Hawaii" => "HI",
        "Idaho" => "ID",
        "Illinois" => "IL",
        "Indiana" => "IN",
        "Iowa" => "IA",
        "Kansas" => "KS",
        "Kentucky" => "KY",
        "Louisiana" => "LA",
        "Maine" => "ME",
        "Maryland" => "MD",
        "Massachusetts" => "MA",
        "Michigan" => "MI",
        "Minnesota" => "MN",
        "Mississippi" => "MS",
        "Missouri" => "MO",
        "Montana" => "MT",
        "Nebraska" => "NE",
        "Nevada" => "NV",
        "New Hampshire" => "NH",
        "New Jersey" => "NJ",
        "New Mexico" => "NM",
        "New York" => "NY",
        "North Carolina" => "NC",
        "North Dakota" => "ND",
        "Ohio" => "OH",
        "Oklahoma" => "OK",
        "Oregon" => "OR",
        "Pennsylvania" => "PA",
        "Rhode Island" => "RI",
        "South Carolina" => "SC",
        "South Dakota" => "SD",
        "Tennessee" => "TN",
        "Texas" => "TX",
        "Utah" => "UT",
        "Vermont" => "VT",
        "Virginia" => "VA",
        "Washington" => "WA",
        "West Virginia" => "WV",
        "Wisconsin" => "WI",
        "Wyoming" => "WY",
        "American Samoa" => "AS",
        "District of Columbia" => "DC",
        "Federated States of Micronesia" => "FM",
        "Guam" => "GU",
        "Marshall Islands" => "MH",
        "Northern Mariana Islands" => "MP",
        "Palau" => "PW",
        "Puerto Rico" => "PR",
        "Virgin Islands" => "VI",
        "Armed Forces Africa" => "AE",
        "Armed Forces Americas" => "AA",
        "Armed Forces Canada" => "AE",
        "Armed Forces Europe" => "AE",
        "Armed Forces Middle East" => "AE",
        "Armed Forces Pacific" => "AP"
    );
    $output = "";
    if($style === true){
        ksort($states);
    }

    $output = "<select name='state'>";
    $output .= "<option value=''>--</option>";

    foreach($states as $name => $abbr){
        $output .= "<option value='" . $abbr . "'";
        if($form === $abbr){
            $output .= "selected='selected'";
        }

        if($style === true){
            $output .= ">" . $abbr . "</option>";
        } else {
            $output .= ">" . $name . "</option>";
        }
    }
    $output .= "</select>";

    return $output;
}
```

To output the dropdown, simply do:

```
echo statesDropdown();
```

Comment: Well, the good news is I had never intended to store such data in a database, because as you said, it almost never changes, unless I need to add US territories or Canadian provinces, at which point I can simply amend my array.

The bad news is I have no experience with classes and little understanding of exactly how they work, so I will have to look at your code above until I understand it (I don't like using what I can't understand).

I did get some feedback on the initial question on SO, which did simplify the original function, but I will update when I have decided which route to take.

Comment: Totally understand - though I would suggest taking the class above as a learning exercise as they play an integral role in programming. I've also gone ahead and modified my answer so that it does not use a class.